# CheckSUR .manifest files from which version?

Tags: windows-7

We have a Windows 7 Home Premium laptop on which SFC fails, therefore we ran CheckSUR but that also fails with various unavailable repair files (.manifest).

Question is can we safely use Windows 7 Professional *.manifest files to repair the faulty Windows 7 Home Premium laptop or are there differences in the .manifest files between the different versions of windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Joseph from Microsoft explained here how to use checkSUR:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2010/05/26/using-checksur-and-update-packages-to-fix-corruption.aspx

run it, look into the generated checkSUR.log which files are damaged and place the MSU files of the damaged updates in `C:\Windows\CheckSUR\packages` and rerun the checkSUR tool.

Comment: Thanks magicandre.  Have read the article you link to but can't see how to find out the name of the relevant .msu file.  We have got 24 of these 'Unavailable repair files'.  For example how would I find the correct .msu for: manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-mitigations-c1_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18076_none_6a093e5f091af840.manifest

Comment: open regedit, go **to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-mitigations-c5_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_8c1eca82f2d07e95** look at the right side for the version number and look which KB it is. Do the same under the **ComponentDetect** key for all other damaged files.

Comment: It seems all of these missing files are related to the following updates:
KB2762895, KB2492386, KB2791765
Now downloaded the 64-bit versions of each of these and copied them into C:\Windows\CheckSUR\Packages.
Rerun CheckSUR  (KB947821) again which has now replaced all the missing files.

Many thanks to magicandre.

Comment: great :) Btw, in **Windows 8** MS listened to my feedback and they included the checkSUR tool in DISM. DISM also downloads all files from the Internet, so you don't have to do those steps.